# Reduction of an arbitrarily (say, r times) nested loop summation into an algebraic formula.

Tags: number-theory, summation

Suppose we have a following summation,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-r+1}\sum_{j=1}^{i}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\sum_{l=1}^k.....(summation\:continued)\sum_{z=1}^y z $$
$$r\:=\:\{1,2,3,4,....n\}\:\:\:(range\:of\:values\:for\:n)$$

#### Inspiration for the formula

Consider n cards numbered from 1 to n. Number of ways of selecting r cards out of n  **in a strictly increasing or decreasing order**  I observed, can be calculated by this formula.

For example, for **n=10**, 

When r=1, the answer is straight forward i.e. 10.

For r=2, we can proceed in a following manner- 
$$ Card\:1=1\:Card\:2=2,3,4,5...10=9\\Card\:1=2\:Card\:2=3,4,5...10=8\\Card \:1=3\:Card \:2=4,5,6...10=7\\Card\:1=4\:Card \:2=5,6,7...10=6\\.......\\.......\\.......\\{Final\:value= 9+8+7+6....+1=45\:(Double\:summation\:by \:above\:summation)}$$
For r=3, we can proceed by the same method to arrive at a triple summation and so on.

#### Initial observations from the formula

1. The value of the summation (*which depends on the value of n*) **does not approach infinity** (*within finite values of n*).
2. It rather behaves as a function with a global maxima somewhere around the middle (**though I must admit it is just an initial observation**).

The functions behaves very much like Permutation (*atleast in terms of values depending on r*). Is it just a simple correlation or is there some sort of **causative resemblance** which would help me to arrive at a more general algebraic formula?

##### Update

***Consider the question closed***

The answer below by @Henry completely answers the question. Though I have to admit, I took a long route to arrive at the answer, but the summation above does show how *combinatorics is equivalent to a nested summation*!

Answer (score 1):

I do not follow all the indices in your summation but in answer to

> Consider $n$ cards numbered from $1$ to $n$. Number of ways of selecting $r$ cards out of $n$  in a strictly increasing or decreasing order

a combinatorial argument will say this is

- $1$ when $n \ge r=0$
- $n$ when $n \ge r =1$
- $2{n \choose r}$ when $n \ge r \ge 2$

since in the last case you select $r$ from $n$ and then have two ways of ordering them

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's right. As for the indices, the summation is just r times nested loop for r i.e. for instance, in the example I gave above, using the methodology I have followed (to derive exclusive and exhaustive cases) you would observe the summation just works as a nested loop running 3 times. In conclusion, the answer just confirmed my gut feeling that there was indeed a causative relation between the summation and a possible combinatorics (for lack of a better word at the moment) formula.